# CheckboxField gives StackOverflow Error in Blackberry java application

Tags: java, blackberry

I am creating 2-3 checkbox field in my screen and adding those in a vertical field manager. Idea here is to disable other check box on click of another checkbox. but it is giving me stackoverflow error. I am posting my code here...

```
final CheckboxField[] checkBoxField = new CheckboxField[2];
checkBoxField[0] = cashCardCheckboxField;
checkBoxField[1] = creditDebitCardCheckboxField;

checkBoxField[0].setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        if(context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC){  //It means manually clicked by User
            if(checkBoxField[0].getChecked()){
                checkBoxField[0].setChecked(false);
            }else{
                checkBoxField[0].setChecked(true);
                //Please wait Screen starts
                // call here a user defined function to populate the drop down list
                //Please wait Screen ends
            }
        }else{
            checkBoxField[0].setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});

checkBoxField[1].setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        if(context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC){  //It means manually clicked by User

            if(checkBoxField[1].getChecked()){
                checkBoxField[1].setChecked(false);
            }else{
                checkBoxField[1].setChecked(true);
                //Please wait Screen starts
                // call here a user defined function to populate the drop down list
                //Please wait Screen ends
            }

        }else{
            checkBoxField[1].setChecked(false);
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: A very similar question has been raised on the BB Forum here:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-checkboxes-Radio-Button-group-like-behaviour-gives/td-p/2600853
However the poster seems unable to review the stack trace to resolve the problem themselves.  The same comment applies here.  Review your stack trace and you will find whereabouts in your code you are causing a recursive invocation of the FieldChangeListener.  It is not hard to find, in fact if you desk check your code you will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Try using this code.  It allows you to create any number of checkboxes.  When **one** is checked, the listener will uncheck all the other ones.

```java
public class CheckBoxScreen extends MainScreen {

   private CheckboxField checkBoxField[];

   public CheckBoxScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      checkBoxField = new CheckboxField[3];
      checkBoxField[0] = new CheckboxField("one", true);  // checked by default
      checkBoxField[1] = new CheckboxField("two", false);
      checkBoxField[2] = new CheckboxField("three", false);

      FieldChangeListener listener = new CheckboxListener();

      for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxField.length; i++) {
         checkBoxField[i].setChangeListener(listener);
         add(checkBoxField[i]);
      }
   }

   private class CheckboxListener implements FieldChangeListener {

      public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

         if (context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC) {
            // user modified this field
            CheckboxField checkbox = (CheckboxField)field;   
            if (checkbox.getChecked()) {              
               // uncheck the other checkboxes
               for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxField.length; i++) {
                  if (checkBoxField[i] != checkbox && checkBoxField[i].getChecked()) {
                     checkBoxField[i].setChecked(false);
                  }
               }
            }
         } else {  
            // nothing more to do here ... this time, fieldChanged() is being
            //  called as a result of calling setChecked() in the code.
         }
      }      
   }
}
```

### Why Your Code Created a Stack Overflow

The `fieldChanged()` method gets called whenever a field has its properties modified.  For a `CheckboxField`, that happens when the field is checked or unchecked.  This can happen either because the **user** checks/unchecks the field, or because your **code** calls `setChecked(boolean)`.  This line:

```java
if(context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC){  //It means manually clicked by User
```

is what allows the code inside `fieldChanged()` to determine if this call is occurring because the user changed the field, or because `setChecked()` was called by your code.   Unfortunately, you have placed calls to `setChecked()` in all branches of the `if` statement, which causes `setChecked()` to be called both for user events, and when your code changes the fields.

In this code:

```java
    checkBoxField[0].setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

            if(context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC){  //It means manually clicked by User
                if(checkBoxField[0].getChecked()){
                    checkBoxField[0].setChecked(false);
                }else{
                    checkBoxField[0].setChecked(true);
                    //Please wait Screen starts
                    // call here a user defined function to populate the drop down list
                    //Please wait Screen ends
                }
            }else{
                checkBoxField[0].setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

it is the last line (`checkBoxField[0].setChecked(false);`) that is causing problems.  That `else` branch is reached after calling `setChecked()` in the *"manually clicked"* branch of the `if` statement.  Once you call `setChecked(false)` again, you have modified the field *programmatically*.  This will cause `fieldChanged()` to be called back again.  And again.  And again.  This loop will never stop, until the program stack is full, and your app crashes.

So, if you see my code, you notice that I am not calling `setChecked()` in the *programmatic* branch of the `if` statement.  Another problem in your code is that you don't have the correct logic to uncheck checkbox 1 when checkbox 0 is checked.  But, that's only a *functional* bug.  The recursive call to `fieldChanged()` is what caused the stack overflow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nate - thanks for doing this.  You will see by my comment above, I had avoided helping here.  I did this because I thought that the two bugs (not resetting the correct Field and incorrect processing in the PROGRAMMATIC branch) would have been clear to anyone looking at the stack trace, using the debugger, or even desk checking the code. So as a learning experience, I thought getting this poster to find the bugs themselves would be a good thing.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @PeterStrange You are right. I tried but could not see/find the stack trace or could not recognize the culprit lines of code which caused the Stackoverflow error....

Comment: @Nate Thanks a lot.. It helped me and solved my problem... and one more thing....EXPLANATION given here by you is GREAT...SUPERB...